# How to dispaly the fist item in recycleview android

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have created the recycleview and all list item was displayed in horizontal format. When I open the app the last item is displayed in first. Initially I want to scroll the list item from left to right. If I open the the app I have scroll the list from right because last item is shown at first. What to do for showing the first item in first in recycleview.

```
 try {
            JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("new_room");

            //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                //   int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("hotel_id").toString());
                String name = jsonObject.optString("hotel_name").toString();
                final String image = jsonObject.optString("logo").toString();
                Log.d("response", "response -----" + image);

                Movie movie = new Movie();

                movie.sethorizontal1_title(jsonObject.optString("room_name").toString());
                movie.sethorizontal1_image(jsonObject.optString("room_images").toString());
                movie.sethorizontal1_roomid(jsonObject.optString("room_id").toString());
                movie.sethorizontal1_city(jsonObject.optString("city").toString());
                movieList.add(movie);

             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                listview1.setAdapter(adapter1);
                listview1.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
                        = new LinearLayoutManager(Home.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                listview1.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();}});

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Adapter

public class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private final Context mcontext;
private final List<Movie> movieItems;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public  TextView horz_title,amount;
    public ImageView horz_image;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        horz_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.horz_title);
         horz_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.horz_image);
    }
}

public HorizontalAdapter(Context mcontext, List<Movie> movieItems) {

    this.mcontext = mcontext;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.horizontal_list, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {



    final Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
    URL url = null;
    String image=m.gethorizontal1_image();
    try {
        url = new URL(image);


        Glide.with(mcontext).load(String.valueOf(url)).into( holder.horz_image);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (m.gethorizontal1_title()!=null){
        if (!m.gethorizontal1_title().equals("null")){
            holder.horz_title.setText(m.gethorizontal1_title());
        }
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //   int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("hotel_id").toString());
            String name = jsonObject.optString("hotel_name").toString();
            final String image = jsonObject.optString("logo").toString();
            Log.d("response", "response -----" + image);

            Movie movie = new Movie();

        movie.sethorizontal1_title(jsonObject.optString("room_name").toString());
            movie.sethorizontal1_image(jsonObject.optString("room_images").toString());
            movie.sethorizontal1_roomid(jsonObject.optString("room_id").toString());
            movie.sethorizontal1_city(jsonObject.optString("city").toString());
            movieList.add(movie);}

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
            listview1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            listview1.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(Home.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,   false);
            listview1.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();}});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Please use above code, I have done some changes in above your code.
And please let me know if not works.
Will find new solution and also please share code of your adapter in that case.**

Comment: Also add these lines.try {
            JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("new_room");

Comment: i have tried your code but its remains same and i have post my adapter code dude

Comment: please any one help me to fix this issue

Comment: Your adapter looks fine, can you check your list which you are preparing to show, may be you are preparing it wrongly.

Comment: you are asking data retrieved from database?

Comment: Sorry for late response, but can you give me the whole code so that I can give you the exact solution.